# stable, stable/updates and stable-updates in the sources.list

Tags: debian, upgrade, deb

Very often now I have seen `sources.list` files (including my own) that contain lines like these:

```
deb     http://security.debian.org/         testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb     http://security.debian.org/         wheezy/updates  main contrib non-free
deb     http://http.debian.net/debian       wheezy-updates  main
```

I understood the meaning of the components (`main`, `contrib` and `non-free`). I also partially understood the meaning of the distribution (`wheezy`, `testing`, `stable` etc.) and that of the path. This is all well documented in [the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

- But what does the `/updates` or `-updates` mean?
- Should I write it with `-` or `/` myself?
- How am I supposed to know that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an explanation of the three source URIs you have listed.

1. wheezy-updates: See [the StableUpdates page on the Debian
   Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates)

   As the page explains,

   > This path will be used for updates which many users may wish to
   > install on their systems before the next point release is made, such
   > as updates to virus scanners and timezone data.

   These were previously known as volatile.
2. Both wheezy/updates and testing/updates are security fixes, to the
   stable release and testing respectively. Security fixes for testing
   are relatively recent, and supported on a best-effort basis.

   These correspond to the pages [Security
   Information](https://www.debian.org/security/) for wheezy/updates
   and [security fixes for
   testing](http://testing-security.debian.net/) for testing/updates.

If you are asking why these have different forms, that is just how the people concerned choose how to have things set up. The `/` forward slash corresponds to the structure of the underlying URL, which in turn corresponds to the directory structure of the corresponding apt repository.

So, for example

1. the source URI

   deb     http://http.debian.net/debian       wheezy-updates  main

   corresponds to the URL

   http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/
2. the source URI

   deb     http://security.debian.org/         testing/updates main
   contrib non-free

   corresponds to the URL

   http://security.debian.org/dists/testing/updates/
3. the source URI

   deb http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
   non-free

   corresponds to the URL

   http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/

Comment: So (in a production environment) one should _never_ only take the `stable` `deb` but _ever_ **also** the `stable/updates`, because the `stable` might have open security issues? (Thanks btw for the nice answer!)

Comment: @Matmarbon No, you should use both. The `stable/updates` only contains security updates. For everything else, you will need the `stable` sources.

Comment: Example nr 1 looks wrong to me? Shouldn't the URL contains `wheezy-updates` instead of `wheezy/updates`?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Can you give more details why you think it's wrong? If you mean the security.debian.org url, then http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/ is hte right form, though I'm not sure why I wrote that that the first URL corresponds to the second.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I meant the first URL. When the distribution is called "wheezy-updates", the URL should also contain "wheezy-updates", and not "wheezy/updates". Stephen Kitt has fixed it now.